# Audio Issues on Dell Vostro 3400 2020 Running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

Since the last three weeks' updates, I have encountered several challenges with the audio functionality on my system. Primarily, upon starting my laptop, the audio often fails to work, displaying "Dummy Output." To resolve this, I find myself needing to restart the laptop two or three times before the audio becomes functional.

Even when the audio is working, I've noticed a recurring issue where, after playing video or audio for approximately 2-3 minutes, the sound starts crackling and buzzing. The intensity of these distortions gradually increases, resembling the static interference on a radio station with a weak signal. This issue persists even when using 3.5mm headphones, requiring the use of a USB headset or Bluetooth headphones to enjoy distortion-free audio.

Furthermore, I have observed that, regardless of the Ubuntu version (ranging from 22.04 to 22.04.3), I face difficulties changing the microphone output settings when an external audio peripheral, such as a USB headset, 3.5mm headphones, or Bluetooth headphones, is connected. The OS appears to exclusively utilize the microphone from the connected peripheral, making it impossible to switch to the laptop's built-in microphone.

For your reference, here are the specifications of my laptop and the Ubuntu version I am currently using:

Laptop: Dell Vostro 3400
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-1135G7
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 Iris Xe
Memory: 2490MiB / 19720MiB
Resolution: 1920x1080
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic
DE: GNOME 42.9
Shell: bash 5.1.16
Sound Card: Card: HDA Intel PCH, Chip: Cirrus Logic CS8409/CS42L42

I want to emphasize that I receive updates from the Tunisia Ubuntu server.

***UPDATE 29-01-2024***
After the latest Linux kernel update to "6.5.0-15-generic."

Following the update, I observed a significant reduction in crackling sound (approximately 80%) after disabling C-states from the BIOS. However, this improvement came at the cost of higher CPU temperatures, with the fan constantly running.

Conversely, with C-states enabled, the crackling sound occurs only when the fan starts working. Additionally, I am still encountering the "Dummy Output" audio issue consistently on a fresh start, necessitating a reboot to resolve.